# Sending json with php and parse it in ajax call

Tags: jquery, parsing

I don't have experience using JSON with php and ajax and I need your help.

I have a php page that validates user input... Before using json, I used to store them in an array. I was able to parse the json when I store my values in an array like this 
    $data = array("success"=>true, "msg"=>"my masg");
    json_decode($data);

and then in my ajax call on success function I data.success and data.msg

How do I store multipe msgs or errors in my array and parse them in my ajax call?
here is my code

here I want to validate user input and I would like to validate many fields

```
    if(isset($_POST['txt_username']) &&($_POST['txt_username']!=""))
    {
        $username =trim( $_POST['txt_username']);
        $username  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'txt_username',
                    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    else
    {

             }
```

So how do I do it in the else statement?

here is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({       
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            data: {txt_username:$("#username").val(), txt_password:$("#password").val()},

            beforeSend: function(x) {

                if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {

                    x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                }

            },

            url: 'proccessing_forms/admin_login.php',

            success: function(data) {

                // parse the data
            }
    });


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multidimensional arrays for this:

```
$msg = array("success" => array(), "error" => array());

// ... DO you processing on if and else

//When you need to add to an success do
$msg['success'][] = "My Success";

//When you need to add to an error do
$msg['error'][] = "My error";


echo json_encode($msg); exit;
```

On the ajax's success event, you can access both of these variables individually.

```
success: function(data) {
    var errors = data.error;
    var succesess = data.success

    //Process each msg
    $.each(errors, function(index, msg) {
         console.log(msg);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can create a JSON string like this:

```
<?php

  $array["error"][] = "message1";
  $array["error"][] = "message2";

  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Then in JavaScript callback function you can use it like this:

```
  success: function(data) 
  {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      alert(key + " - " + val);
    });
  }
```

Of course you should notice that now `val` is an array due to my change in PHP and you have to run another loop on it to get your content:

```
  success: function(data) 
  {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
        alert(key2 + " - " + val2);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: But how do you populate the array with more than one input? like what do I do when I validate the next user input? if I do the same as you did with all user input, then it will overwrite it

Comment: @user2589904 Actually I'm not sure what are you asking for about `more than one input`. Think it's better that you provide an example.